# How can I fix Cannot assign valueof type 'Double' to 'String?' in Swift3

Tags: swift3

I'am a swift beginner then want to write a BMI counting.

A error Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to 'String?'

appear in label.text = GetBMI(H: myH, W: myW)

How can I fix it ?

```
   @IBAction func calBMI(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if Height.text != nil && Weight.text != nil {
        let myH : Double = (Height.text! as AnyObject).doubleValue
        let myW : Double = (Weight.text! as AnyObject).doubleValue
     label.text = GetBMI(H: myH, W: myW)
    }
    else {
        label.text = "Please enter your Height and Weight!"
    }
}

func GetBMI(H: Double, W: Double) -> Double {
    let height: Double = H / 100
    return  W / (height * height)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find some threads describing how to fix **Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to 'String?'**, but unfortunately those threads may not point out some bad parts of your code.

If I were to fix all such parts:

```
@IBOutlet var heightField: UITextField! //Renamed `Height` to `heightField`
@IBOutlet var weightField: UITextField! //Renamed `Weight` to `weightField`
@IBAction func calBMI(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if //Optional binding (using `if-let`) is the more preferred way than `!= nil` and forced unwrapping.
        let heightText = heightField.text,
        let weightText = weightField.text,
        //You should not use `(... as AnyObject).doubleValue` to convert `String` to `Double`
        //and should check if the text values are valid representation of Double
        let myH = Double(heightText),
        let myW = Double(weightText)
    {
        //This is the key point for the error "Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to 'String?'"
        label.text = String(getBMI(h: myH, w: myW)) //You need to convert `Double` to `String`
    }
    else {
        label.text = "Please enter your Height and Weight!"
    }
}

//Renamed `GetBMI(H:W:)` to `getBMI(h:w:)`
func getBMI(h: Double, w: Double) -> Double {
    let height: Double = h / 100
    return  w / (height * height)
}
```

Some points:

- Property names should represent the content's feature. In your code, you use `height` and `weight` as `Double` values, so you'd better name `UITextField`s (assuming `Height` and `Weight` are `UITextField`s) with something other. I renamed them to `heightField` and `weightField`.
- **Testing with `!= nil` and then applying forced unwrapping (`!`) is not a preferred way, you'd better avoid using `!` as much as possible. Better use Optional binding -- `if-let`**.
- **You should not use `(... as AnyObject).doubleValue` to convert `String` to `Double`. You can use the initializer of `Double` to convert `String` to `Double` (#1). Which returns `Optional<Double>`, so better include them in `if-let`**.
- **You cannot directly assign `Double` value to a property of type `String?`. You can use the initializer of `String` to convert `Double` to `String` (#1)**.
- In Swift, you usually use capitalized identifier only for types, so I renamed `GetBMI(H:W:)` to `getBMI(h:w:)`.

(#1) Using initializers when converting between `String` and `Double` is sort of a simplified way. It may be sufficient for making a *BMI Calculator tutorial code*, but may not be sufficient for actual apps. Consider using `NSNumberFormatter` for actual apps.

**Bold lines** are mandatory or strongly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

```
label.text = String(GetBMI(H: myH, W: myW))
```

Your function returns a double, the label.text will only accept a string. Hence the error message you get: Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to 'String?.

The question mark in the error might of thrown you off. The ? on 'String?' is there because the label.text MIGHT be empty, so its an 'optional' ie: may or may not have a value. Opposite of ! which explicitly declares there is a value and is != nil.